# I'm Brazilian, holding a B visa, in Canada right now. Am I alowed to enter USA?

Tags: visas, usa, transit, canada, international-travel

I am Brazilian, holding a B Visa. I am in Vancouver, Canada right now and need to go back to Brazil.

Am I allowed to go to USA? I need to stay overnight because there's just one flight from here to LAX, where I can catch the flight.

Comment: B Visa, do you mean US B1/B2 visa?

Comment: How long have you been in Canada? Do you have proof that you were there for over 14 days?

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you have a US B2 visitor visa, yes, you can enter (including transit which requires entering) the US by air (as long as you have not been to [Mainland China](https://www.federalregister.gov/documents/2020/02/05/2020-02424/suspension-of-entry-as-immigrants-and-nonimmigrants-of-persons-who-pose-a-risk-of-transmitting-2019), [Iran](https://www.federalregister.gov/documents/2020/03/04/2020-04595/suspension-of-entry-as-immigrants-and-nonimmigrants-of-certain-additional-persons-who-pose-a-risk-of), [the Schengen Area](https://www.federalregister.gov/documents/2020/03/16/2020-05578/suspension-of-entry-as-immigrants-and-nonimmigrants-of-certain-additional-persons-who-pose-a-risk-of), [the UK, Ireland](https://www.federalregister.gov/documents/2020/03/18/2020-05797/suspension-of-entry-as-immigrants-and-nonimmigrants-of-certain-additional-persons-who-pose-a-risk-of), or [Brazil](https://www.federalregister.gov/documents/2020/05/28/2020-11616/suspension-of-entry-as-immigrants-and-nonimmigrants-of-certain-additional-persons-who-pose-a-risk-of) in the previous 14 days).

However, you cannot enter the US by land (e.g. drive to Seattle to take a flight). Entry to the US across a land border is [currently limited](https://www.federalregister.gov/documents/2020/08/21/2020-18470/temporary-travel-restrictions-applicable-to-land-ports-of-entry-and-ferries-service-between-the) to essential travel, and that restriction has recently been extended to September 21.

Comment: No references, we should just take your word?

Comment: @user56513: It's hard to prove a negative (i.e. that there are no restrictions). I added some references of some restrictions that do not apply, if that would help.

Answer (score 4):

If you hold a B1 and or B2 visa, you can enter USA, whether it is to spend a night or to transit.

USA has no "transit" anyway, they have no "airside" services, os staying for a night or 30 days is basically the same.

**COVID related information:**

If you have been to Brazil or any of the following countries (even if transit) in the past 14 days you will not be allowed to enter or transit USA:

> Austria, Belgium, Brazil, Czechia, Denmark, Estonia, Finland, France, Germany, Greece, Hungary, Iceland, Ireland (Rep.), Italy, Latvia, Liechtenstein, Lithuania, Luxembourg, Malta, Netherlands, Norway, Poland, Portugal, Slovakia, Slovenia, Spain, Sweden, Switzerland or in the United Kingdom (excluding overseas territories outside of Europe)

Source: [iatatravelcentre.com](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/)